# Is there a way to integrate a Django application with a pre-existing Squarespace site?

Tags: django, squarespace

I have a client who has a pre-made Squarespace site who has asked me to build polling and article pages as well as a user database. I did this using Django, but am unsure if I can integrate the third party application with their site.

I contacted Squarespace, they told me they themselves do not provide support on third-party applications. They pointed me towards forums to gather more information. Any information would help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, you can't add server-side code such as Django to a Squarespace site. Squarespace only supports the addition of HTML, CSS and Javascript within [Code Injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection), [Code Blocks](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543167-Using-Code-Blocks), or even [Developer Mode](https://developers.squarespace.com/quick-start).

From [Squarespace's Docs](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815928-Adding-custom-code-to-your-site):

> You can't add server-side code. Server-side code is handled by a server, not by a browser, and includes:
>   - PHP 
>   - Ruby 
>   - Ruby on Rails 
>   - SQL